# Why can't I access a custom hierarchy field on `User`?

Tags: custom-field, user-record

I have two custom hierarchy fields on `User`.

[image: Fields]

When I access a user and click "Edit," I have access to one of these fields but not the other.

[image: Editable fields]

I've double-checked the following:

- I'm logged in as my own account.
- My user record has the "Core User" permissions set.
- The "Core User" permission set give read and edit access to both fields.

[image: Field permissions]

Note that this isn't the *only* custom User field that isn't visible in the user's edit page. There are some picklists and a few others too that aren't visible. But this `PreferredLO__c` is currently the only one that matters.

What exactly determines if a custom user field appears on the user's edit page?

Comment: Check the page layout. Much of the User page is fixed in layout, but all custom stuff needs to be added through the layout definition.

Comment: @PhilW, that's it. Please answer the question so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the page layout. Much of the `User` page is fixed in layout, but all custom fields need to be added through the layout definition. These fields can be put into separate sections - they cannot be added to the standard sections that are uneditable.